# Error: Input 0 of layer dense_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1

Tags: python, tensorflow, redes-neuronales, keras, inteligencia-artificial

estoy programando una Generative Adversarial Network en mi proceso de aprendizaje en el mundo de la Inteligencia Artificial y el Machine Learning, y me he encontrado con un error que no logro solucionar, el error es el siguiente:

```
Input 0 of layer dense_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1
```

el código de mi modelo es el siguiente:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import zipfile
from google.colab import files
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
from imageio import imread, imwrite 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Reshape, Conv2DTranspose, BatchNormalization, Conv2D, LeakyReLU, Flatten, Input, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

print('GPU available:', tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print('tensorflow version:',tf.__version__)
print('keras version:', tf.keras.__version__)

"""---
# Cargamos los datos de entrada
---
"""

zip_location = '/content/drive/MyDrive/IA/datasets/frutas.zip' 
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_location, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall('/tmp')
zip_ref.close()

train_dir = '/tmp/frutas/train/manzanas' #os.path.join(generic_train_dir, 'manzanas')

def load_data():
  filelist = os.listdir(train_dir)

  num_images = len(filelist)
  x_train = np.zeros((num_images, 256, 256, 3)) 
  for i, fname in enumerate(filelist):
    if fname != '.DS_Store':
      imagen = imread(os.path.join(train_dir, fname))
      x_train[i,:] = (imagen - 127.5) / 127.5

  return x_train

x_train = load_data()
x_train.shape

def visualizar_imagen(nimagen, x_train):
  img = (x_train[nimagen, :] * 127.5) + 127.5
  img = np.ndarray.astype(img, np.uint8)
  plt.imshow(img.reshape(256, 256, 3))
  print(img.shape)
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()

print('imagen real para entrenar')
visualizar_imagen(100, x_train)

def print_fake_images(epoch, generador, ejemplos=16, dim=(4,4), figsize=(10,10)):
    ruido = np.random.normal(0,1, [ejemplos, 100])
    imagenes_generadas = generador.predict(ruido)
    imagenes_generadas.reshape(ejemplos, 256, 256, 3)
    imagenes_generadas = imagenes_generadas*127.5 + 127.5
    plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    for i in range(ejemplos):
        plt.subplot(dim[0],dim[1], i+1)
        plt.imshow(imagenes_generadas[i].astype('uint8'), interpolation='nearest')
        plt.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('GAN_imagen_generada_%d.png' %epoch)
    plt.close()

def generar_imagenes(generador,nimagenes):
    ruido = np.random.normal(0,1,[nimagenes,100])
    imagenes_generadas = generador.predict(ruido)
    imagenes_generadas.reshape(nimagenes, 256, 256, 3)
    imagenes_generadas = imagenes_generadas * 127.5 + 127.5
    imagenes_generadas.astype('uint8')
    for i in range(nimagenes):
        imwrite(os.path.join(ejemplos,'ejemplo_'+str(i)+'.png'),imagenes_generadas[i].reshape(256, 256, 3))

"""---
# Definimos el modelo del generador
---
"""

ALPHA = 0.2
MY_OPTIMIZER = Adam(learning_rate = 0.002, beta_1 = 0.5)
LOSS_FUNCTION = 'binary_crossentropy' # 0 | 1
BATCH_SIZE = 128

def create_generator():
  model = Sequential()
  
  model.add(Dense(1024*4*4, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  model.add(Reshape((4,4,1024)))
  #4x4x1024
  
  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(512,(5,5),strides=(2,2),padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  #8x8x512
  
  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(256,(5,5),strides=(2,2),padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  #16x16x256
  
  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128,(5,5),strides=(2,2),padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  #32x32x128

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64,(5,5),strides=(2,2),padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  #64x64x64

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(3, (5,5),strides=(2,2),padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(Activation('tanh'))
  #128x128x3

  model.compile(optimizer = MY_OPTIMIZER, loss = LOSS_FUNCTION)
  
  return model

generator = create_generator()
generator.summary()

"""---
# Creamos el modelo del discriminador
---
"""

def create_discriminator():
  model = Sequential()

  model.add(Conv2D(64, (5,5), strides=(2,2), padding='same', input_shape=(128, 128, 3), use_bias=False))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  #64x64x64

  model.add(Conv2D(128, (5,5), strides=(2,2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  #32x32x128

  model.add(Conv2D(256, (5,5), strides=(2,2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  #16x16x256

  model.add(Conv2D(512, (5,5), strides=(2,2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  #8x8x512

  model.add(Conv2D(1024, (5,5), strides=(2,2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  #4x4x1024

  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', use_bias=False))

  model.compile(optimizer = MY_OPTIMIZER, loss = LOSS_FUNCTION)

  return model

discriminator = create_discriminator()
discriminator.summary()

"""---
# Creamos la Generative Adversarial Network
---
"""

def create_GAN(generator, discriminator):
  model = Sequential()

  model.add(generator)
  
  discriminator.trainable = False
  model.add(discriminator)
  
  model.compile(optimizer = MY_OPTIMIZER, loss = LOSS_FUNCTION)

  return model

gan = create_GAN(generator, discriminator)
gan.summary()

batch_num = x_train.shape[0] / 256

for i in range(1, 5000 + 1):
  print('Epochs: {}'.format(str(i)))

  #Batch de imágenes falsas
  noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, [BATCH_SIZE, 100])
  fake_batch = generator.predict(noise)

  #Batch de imágenes reales
  idx = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = x_train.shape[0], size = BATCH_SIZE)
  real_batch = x_train[idx]

  #Calculamos el error
  discriminator.trainable = True

  real_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(real_batch, np.ones(BATCH_SIZE) * 0.9)
  fake_loss = discriminator.train_on_batch(fake_batch, np.zeros(BATCH_SIZE) * 0.1)

  discriminator.trainable = False

  #Entrenamos la GAN con ruido aleatorio
  gan_loss = gan.train_on_batch(noise, np.ones(BATCH_SIZE))

  #Mostramos por pantalla las imágenes generadas cada 100 iteraciones
  if i == 1 or 1 % 1000 == 0:
    print_fake_images(i, generator)
    generator.save('/content/generator.h5')

generar_imagenes(generator, 100)
```

no logro saber porque me falla, el shape de mis imágenes es de `(256, 256, 3)` creo que pueden ir por ahí los tiros pero no logro encontrar la solución, el error me indica que falla al definir `real_loss` ¿Alguien sabe que está mal o donde esta el fallo para solucionar el error? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he logrado solucionar añadiendo al modelo del Generador una capa de tamaño 32, tal que ahora el modelo del Generador tiene la siguiente forma:

```
def create_generator():
  model = Sequential()
  
  model.add(Dense(1024*4*4, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  model.add(Reshape((4,4,1024)))
  
  
  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(512,(5,5),strides=(2,2),padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
  
  
  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(256,(5,5),strides=(2,2),padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
 
  
  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128,(5,5),strides=(2,2),padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
 

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64,(5,5),strides=(2,2),padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.3))
  model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha = ALPHA))
 

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(32, (5,5),strides=(2,2),padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(Activation('tanh'))
 

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(3, (5,5),strides=(2,2),padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(Activation('tanh'))
 

  model.compile(optimizer = MY_OPTIMIZER, loss = LOSS_FUNCTION)
  
  return model
```